# How to check IsExisting in Anguilla while doing RTF Validation

Tags: rtf

How do I check whether an object exists based on its WebDAV URL in Anguila while doing some RTF validation?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question a bit more, it is rather vague what you are trying to accomplish? Like, what object are you referring to exactly and what type of RTF validation are you doing etc. etc.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any way to check if an item exists in the Content Manager from the CME, except for trying to load it and handling the failure. But that would still log an error on the server.

I'd say create a small web service method that takes the WebDAV URL or item URI as an argument and calls *IsExistingObject* on the Core Service. If you need to check for multiple items at once, you could instead call *GetSystemWideList* with a *RepositoryLocalObjectsFilterData* and the *ItemIds* property set, and check if any of the items are missing from the result. That would perform much better than individual calls.